# How do I LINQify this?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there any way to clean up this type of loop using LINQ?

```
  List<Car> result;
  List<string> makes;
  List<string> models;

  for (int i = 0; i < makes.Count() && i < models.Count(); i++)
  {
    result.Add(new Car() { Make = makes[i], Model = models[i] });
  }
```

Basically I'm looking for some way to collate multiple arrays of individual fields into a single array of objects made up of those fields.

Comment: why you haven't a constructor for Car with 2 parameters... Make and Model... ?

Comment: I didn't have one in this case but that would clean things up a bit.  I do like the syntax above though since it allows you to keep from exposing fields in two places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `Enumerable.Range`, like so:

```
List<Car> result = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(makes.Count, models.Count))
    .Select(i => new Car { Make = makes[i], Model = models[i] }).ToList();
```

If `makes` and `models` always contain the same number of items, you can use more compact syntax:

```
List<Car> result = makes.Select((make, i) => new Car { Make = make, Model = models[i] }).ToList();
```

Comment: This works but I was hoping there would be something more syntactically compact.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show an overload of Select() that allows more compact syntax.

Comment: Need a ToList() on the second answer. +1

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you really need a new LINQ operator - one which wasn't included in LINQ, somewhat accidentally: Zip. It would basically take two enumerables and return a single enumerable which paired entries, until one or other of the original sequences finished.

I don't have anything like that up my sleeve, but it shouldn't take too long to write if you're interested. The resulting code would be something like:

```
List<Car> cars = makes.Zip(models)
                      .Select(pair => new Car(pair.First, pair.Second))
                      .ToList();
```

Let me know if you'd be interested in this and I'll code it up in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil).

Comment: Actually this would be perfect, even better if it could "Zip" more than just 2 enumerables.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how frequently you are going to need to write LINQ queries against these arrays, it may be worth building a class that wraps the arrays and implements `IEnumerable<Car>`.  Then your code looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<Car> cars = new MyClass(makes, models);
var result = from cars...
```

It's not especially complicated to build this; it's just four simple methods (well, six, if you count constructors) spread across two classes (you also need to implement `IEnumerator<Car>`).

This approach keeps you from having to embed implementation details in all of your LINQ queries.  Also, if you've never done this, it's really something worth learning.  Being comfortable implementing `IEnumerable<T>` significantly expands the space of things that you can readily use LINQ for.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Car> result = makes
                   .Take(model.Count)
                   .Select((make, index) => new Car {Make = make, Model = models[index]});
```

Note that this works even if makes and models aren't the same length.